# Unable to render Images in template

Tags: python, django

I have tried so many things to fix this issue but still I can't get it to work.

I can't get my MEDIA images to render correctly in the template, although the url in the page source is the correct absolute path, still the images won't appear.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
import os

class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    db = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    def __unicode__(self) :
        return unicode(self.user) or u''
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Contact
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def user_page(request,user_name):
    try : 
        user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
    except User.DoesNotExists :
        return (request,'main.html')
    return render(request,'main/user_page.html',{'user':user})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<user_name>\w+)/$',views.user_page , name = 'main_page'),
    ]

if settings.DEBUG :
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

main/user_page.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}


    <h1>{{user.username}}</h1>
    <img src="{{user.contact.db.url}}" alt="My image"/>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_root')

STATIC_DIR = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media') 

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Thanks and sorry for the bad english

Comment: @Brobin: Did you try that? It will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Is wrong. Quote form documentation:

> [FileField.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)
>   A local filesystem path that will be
>   appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url
>   attribute.

Thus:

```
db = models.ImageField(upload_to="foo")
```

Will upload to MEDIA_ROOT + "foo".

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead:

**models.py:**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    db = models.ImageField(upload_to=some_folder_here)

    def __unicode__(self) :
        return unicode(self.user) or u''

    def get_db_url(self):
        return "{}{}".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.db)
```

**views.py:**

```
def user_page(request,user_name):
    try : 
        user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
        photo = Contact.objects.filter(user=user)
    except User.DoesNotExists :
        return (request,'main.html')
    context = {
        'user': user',
        'photo': photo
    }
    return render(request,'main/user_page.html', context)
```

**html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{{ photo.get_db_url }}" alt="My image" />
```